# BackEndUrl is undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, undefined

I created a plugin, which should post some data to my backend. I tried to set up some backend url config. I checked the URl within my plugin with "console.log(...)" as u can see withn my code (in sendDataToBackEnd.js). But i getting following output "undefined".This is the error: "Error message:  Cannot read property 'backEndUrl' of null"

Project structure:

```
project1
   public
     backend-config.js
     faviocon.ico
     index.html
   src
     App.vue
     main.js
     config
       backEndUrlConfig.js
     plugin
       sendDataToBackEnd.js
```

Therefore I created backend-config.js within in Folder "public"

```
(function (window) {

    window._backendconfig = {
        urlBackend: `http://localhost:8090/api/auth/event`,
    }

}(this));
```

My config.js looks like this:

```
export default { ...window._backendconfig }
```

And my PLugin "sendDataToBackEnd.js" looks like this:

```
import url from '../../config/backendURLconfig';

var backEndUrl = url.urlBackend;
console.log(backEndUrl)

const sendDatatoBackEnd = {}

sendDataToBackEnd.install = function (Vue){  
    {Method to send Data to my Backend}
}

export default sendDatatoBackEnd;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing using global scope JS (setting a property on window) in your config file with module style JS in your `sendDataToBackEnd.js` file (importing and exporting from modules).

You either need to export something from config (best option if you're using modules), or just access it from the window.

backendURLconfig.js

```
const config = {
  urlBackend: `http://localhost:8090/api/auth/event`,
}

export default config
```

sendDataToBackEnd.js

```
import config from '../config/backendURLconfig';

var backEndUrl = config.urlBackend;

console.log(backEndUrl)

const sendDatatoBackEnd = {}

vuePlugin.install = function (Vue){  
    {Method to send Data to my Backend}
}

export default sendDatatoBackEnd;
```

Comment: Thanks for your example. I tried it,  but still getting the same error
If i declare ```var backEndUrl = `http://localhost:8090/api/auth/event```` it works. I dont understand, why  i cant ouput the url correctly. Do u have any other solutions in your mind?

Comment: What change did you make exactly? If you're still setting the value on `window` in    `backend-config.js` but never importing that file, that code will never run.

Try adding `import "../../public/config/backend-config.js"` before `export default { ...window._backendconfig }`

But, honestly, you're better getting rid of setting it on `window` entirely if you're using modules. Part of the point of modules is avoid polluting the global scope.

Comment: I just changed backendURLconfig.js. Okay i`ll try it!

Comment: What is the best solution in your opinion?

Comment: Best solution is to simplify. Honestly, if you don't need that config anywhere else, just define it in `sendDataToBackEnd.js`. But, let's say that's not what you want. OK, you should still get rid of your IIFE `(function () { })()` where you set it on the window. Again, unless you _really_ need that for some code you can't control that doesn't use modules.

So then, instead of `export default { ...window._backendconfig }`, you can just export the config directly that you were setting in the other file, instead of just accessing it from window and re-exporting.

Comment: Thanks for that! I'll just define it in sendDataToBackEnd.js

Comment: I would still encourage you to try to get it working so you can understand a bit more about what's going on in the code.

Remember: even if you have an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) like you have in your question where you set the object to `window`, that code will not run unless it's imported by another module or added to the HTML document as a script tag.

So, what it looks like was happening is you were exporting your config from that module, trying to read the value from `window`, but that value was never set, so it's undefined.

Comment: Just one more question:
I changed backendURLconfig.js + sendDataToBackEnd.js like above. Still getting the same error "undefined". The variable is defined and imported correctly in my eyes.

Comment: Hmm, without more context about your project it's hard to say. It's the same error? Can you post a stracktrace?

Comment: Got not trace. Just catched this with "Error message:  Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL"